# MS Access - Saving link to another table with msoFileDialogFolderPicker , other then "me"

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to save a link location using msoFileDialogFolderPicker. I want to save the link inside another table with the name of "Characterization results" to field named "PL Reports".

How i can refer to a field in another table like: PL Reports_Characterization results ?

Thanks

```
Private Sub Load_HyperlinkBTN_Click()

   Const msoFileDialogFolderPicker As Long = 4

   Dim fd As Object
'Create a FileDialog object as a File Picker dialog box.
   Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
'Use a With...End With block to reference the FileDialog object.
   With fd
'Set the initial path to the D:\Documents\ folder.
  ' InitialFileName = "\\ap1\tools\db\"
   .Title = "Select Attachment"
'Use the Show method to display the File Picker dialog box and return the user's action.
'If the user presses the action button...
   If .Show = -1 Then
'   DoCmd.GoToRecord , "", acNewRec
    Me![Charactisation results_PL Reports] = "#" & .SelectedItems(1) & "#"

'  **

'If the user presses Cancel...
   Else
   End If
 End With

'Set the object variable to Nothing.
   Set fd = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Can open a recordset object or run an SQL UPDATE or INSERT action. Strongly advise not to use space in naming convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should insert a new record in table `Characterization results` and save the value `.SelectedItems(1)` in the field `PL Reports`:

`CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO [Characterization results] ([PL Reports]) VALUES ('" & .SelectedItems(1) & "');", dbFailOnError`

P.S. You should really avoid using space in names as @June7 stated.

Comment: If this fits you, please accept it as an answer.

Comment: How do i accept as an answer ?

Comment: Click on the check mark to the left of the answer to make it green. Thanks.